# Strength of BTEE

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

What is the consistency strength of Basic Theory of Elementary Embeddings (BTEE) from [The spectrum of elementrary embeddings j : V → V](http://pcorazza.lisco.com/papers/spectrum_embeddings.pdf) by Paul Corazza?

BTEE uses the language of $(V,∈,j)$ and asserts:
ZFC (without separation and replacement for formulas using $j$)
(schema) $j$ a is nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into $V$ (for formulas without $j$)
critical point: the least ordinal moved by $j$ exists.

Without critical point, the theory would be conservative over ZFC.  With full replacement (and given the axiom of choice), the theory would be inconsistent; and there is a hierarchy between the two extremes.

BTEE suffices for a basic theory of $j$.  For every natural number $n$, BTEE proves that $κ = \mathrm{crit}(j)$ is $n$-ineffable and totally indescribable (see the linked paper).  However, the only upper bound on the strength of BTEE in the paper is $ω$-Erdős.

This question is in [Q/A format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTEE is conservative over the stationary reflection principle (SRP), i.e. ZFC + (schema) {there is $n$-subtle cardinal}$_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$. Using $n$-ineffable in the schema is equivalent.

Note that we get conservativity and not just equiconsistency, and also that (without full conservativity) SRP shows up in a number of other results including in a basic axiomatization of [reflective cardinals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2270) of finite orders (an extension of the language of set theory), and (separately) in Harvey Friedman's natural arithmetic statements independent of ZFC.

As noted above, for every $n$, BTEE implies existence of $n$-subtle cardinals.

For the converse, given a proposition $A$, consistency of ZFC + $A$ + (schema) {there is $n$-subtle cardinal}$_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ implies existence of a model $M$ of ZFC + $A$ + $n$-subtle cardinal for a nonstandard number $n$, plus existence of $λ$ with $V_λ^M≺M$.  Fix such an $M$ and an $M$-well-ordering $<^*$ of $V_λ^M$, and (in $M$; $n$ is nonstandard outside of $M$) use an $n$-subtle cardinal $<λ$ to produce an $n$-tuple $(κ_1,...,κ_n)$ of good indiscernibles for $(V_λ^M, ∈^M, <^*)$.  ("good" is a technical term here and is why we need the $n$-subtle cardinal; it will ensure that $j$ does not move $M$-ordinals below $κ_1$.)  Let $M'$ be the $(V_λ^M, ∈^M, <^*)$ Skolem hull of the first $ω$ of these indiscernibles (as computed in $V$ so all Gödel numbers are standard).  $(M',∈^M,j)$ satisfies BTEE + $A$ where $j(κ_i)=κ_{i+1}$ and $j$ is extended to all sets in $M'$ using the Skolem hull.

Adding induction (and especially transfinite induction) would significantly increase the strength.  For the strength of existence of a well-founded model of BTEE, see this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319231/consistency-strength-of-jl-%CE%B4%E2%86%92l-%CE%B4-for-some-%CE%B4).

*$n$-huge cardinals*

Nonstandard models can also be used to show that WA<sub>0</sub> (bounded quantifier Wholeness Axiom, which consists of BTEE and separation for bounded quantifier $j$-formulas) is conservative over ZFC + (schema) {there is $n$-huge $κ$ with $V_κ≺_{Σ_n}V$}$_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ .  (In turn, this is $Σ_2^V$ conservative over ZFC + (schema) {there is $n$-huge $κ$}$_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ .)

One direction is proved in the linked paper.  For the converse, given a proposition $A$, consistency of ZFC + $A$ + (schema) {there is $n$-huge $κ$ with $V_κ≺_{Σ_n}V$}$_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ implies existence of a model $M$ of ZFC + $A$ + $n$-huge cardinal $κ$ for a nonstandard number $n$, and with $V_κ^M≺M$.  Starting with such $M$ and an $n$-huge embedding $j$ in $M$ with $κ = \mathrm{crit}(j)$, let $M' = \{x∈M: ∃m<ω \,\, x ∈^M j^m(V_κ^M)\}$.  (Note that we use $ω$ rather than $ω^M$.) $(M', ∈^M, j)$ satisfies WA<sub>0</sub> + $A$.